# Websocket server: wcf or console application on mono environment

Tags: .net, wcf, mono, websocket

I've been investigating on how to build a websocket service to be run on mono and my question is mostly on software design. Goal is to achieve a .Net WCF (or similar) service that web clients communicate to without page refreshes and have information updated on the browser ui without user input.

I know mono does not support System.Net.WebSockets but one thing I tried is a WCF service with a custombinding in the web.config, to avoid using the Microsoft web socket classes. Of course mono started complaining about Unrecognized element 'webSocketSettings'.

Here is the binding I used for my test wcf service:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
      <byteStreamMessageEncoding/>
      <httpTransport>
        <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always" 
                           createNotificationOnConnection="true"/>
      </httpTransport>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Knowing this I assume mono does not support web socket binding either.

Question is, is there currently any way to configure either a wcf service or even a console application (run as daemon on a linux server over mono) to communicate over web sockets? That is, *without* using any 3rd party libraries and hosting it on a Linux server using mono? If not, what are my options? Using a 3rd party library, building something like a web client that polls a wcf service method using ajax etc?

I will appreciate any comments.

Thanks,
Olli

Answer (score 1):

In case you cannot manage to make it work in Mono, I develop a WebSocket component named [WebSocketListener](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/) that supports it. Take a look on [this guide about how to use it in Mono](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/Mono-support).

Comment: Thanks @vtortola, Your work seems excellent and definetely worth looking into. I'll go for the simplest suitable solution I can find, preferrably something without external libraries but will look into that if I don't find other solutions that would be better suitable for my goal. Keep up the good work!